# Clean-out plug in p-trap won't screw back on

Tags: p-trap

I had to remove the clean-out plug of a sink P-trap to clear a clog. Underneath, there was hardened sediment that I had to break apart with a small knife.  Now that I have the drain cleared, the clean-out plug won't screw back on.  I don't see any tape or rust on it and tried to clean the thread of the pipe as well.  My house was built in 1947--not sure if this is original pipe or not.  Is there a way to get it to screw back on?  It almost seems too small at this point.  Thanks.

Comment: As with the previous question, pictures are really your best way to get an answer.  I can't even picture this P-trap with a clean out that you're talking about.

Comment: Camera not working.  P-trap is metal and at the bottom of the u-bend, there is a clean-out.  It looks like the one in the following link, except there is no slip nut on the wall side.  https://www.us.kohler.com/us/Adjustable-P-trap-with-tubing-outlet,-1-1-4-x-1-1-4/productDetail/sink-fittings/420309.htm

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the plug in a floor drain. If so, sometimes the threads get mucked up. Often you can just clean them with some Limeaway or another decalcification product. If that's not working go to your local hardware store or HD and buy an expandable rubber drain plug. These plugs are about 1 or so inches in diameter and have a wing nut on one side and a metal washer on the other. You pop it in the drain plug hole and as you tighten the wingnut the rubber between the wingnut and the washer compresses and expands. Works like a charm.

Comment: Here's a link to one:https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-2-in-Gripper-Mechanical-Plastic-Test-Plug-33401/100346775

Comment: It is the clean-out plug of the metal trap of a bathroom sink--I had left that out.  Trying vinegar to clean it.  Would the expandable rubber drain plug work for that as well?

Comment: Now I think I understand you. If you're talking about a P trap under a bathroom sink just buy a new P trap and put it in. I thought you were referring to a cleanout plug on a floor drain. Pictures are always good when trying to solve these problems.